# Sending photos and multiple data to the controller with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax

I am sending the selected photo to my controller in asp.net core with ajax and javascript. Thanks to the code below:

```
<form id="form" name="form" style="display:none;" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input  onchange="uploadFiles('files');" class="form-control" type="file" id="files">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My javascript and ajax codes:

```
var sliderFotografEkle = "@Url.Action("sliderFotoKayit", "slider")";

function uploadFiles(inputId) {
    var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    var files = input.files;
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", files[i]);
    }


    $.ajax(
        {
            url: sliderFotografEkle,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Files Uploaded!");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

It only takes formData in the data part. I want to send a second data. It doesn't send. Probably
processData: false,
contentType: false, from what I gave. but if i don't give them it doesn't send the photo this time. Please help me.

this is where the parameters are given in the controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> sliderFotoKayit(slider item, List<IFormFile> files)
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to send multiple image at the same time?

Comment: No. I will not send multiple files. The second data I will send is int. value. not file.

for example:

Data:{"formData":formData, "id": id}


As.....

Answer (score 1):

I already tested your code on ASP.NET Core 3.1 and found no problem uploading one file at a time.

As I understand, you problem is that you cannot choose and send multiple files at once.

For choosing and sending multiple files at once, your html input tag must have a `multiple` attribute. Otherwise, it only allows you to choose one file at a time.

```html
<input onchange="uploadFiles('files');" class="form-control" type="file" id="files" multiple>
```

---

#### Updated after the author provided more context:

For any additional value you want to send in your form data, just you `append(key: string, value: any)` method.

Updated JS with an additional `int` field:

```
function uploadFiles(inputId) {
    var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
    var files = input.files;
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", files[i]);
    }

    formData.append("id", 3); // append additional int field here

    $.ajax(
        {
            url: sliderFotografEkle,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Files Uploaded!");
            }
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

Controller method signature to receive files and an additional `int` field:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleFileUpload(int id, List<IFormFile> files)
```

#### Some more details:

When you send form data to the server, request will have `content-type: multipart/form-data;`. As one HTTP request can just have one content-type, there are 2 choices:

- The **easy** way: Add new fields to form, either through `input` fields in html or `formData.append(key, value)` in js. This is recommended because:

  1. `content-type: multipart/form-data;` can include both files and any other types that HTML form support.
  2. `content-type: multipart/form-data;` has built-in support in ASP.NET, so form content will automatically bind to controller method parameters.

- The **hard** way: Serialize formdata into string, then return `content-type: application/json;`. Do this if you don't have control over the server, usually in cases when you have to conform to the API of another server. This is clearly more flexible, but also more complicated.

You will be able to have the data in the form:

```json
{
    "formData": serializedFormData, 
    "id": id
}
```

The biggest drawback is that the server then have to manually deserialize the form data.

Comment: `multiple` attribute is HTML built-in. For appending all files in the input field to the FormData, there is already a loop in the author's js code.

Comment: No. I will not send multiple files. The second data I will send is int. value. not file.

for example:

Data:{"formData":formData, "id": id}

As.....

Comment: OMG. I've done the same before and it didn't work. But now that you said it, I did the same again and it worked. but everything was the same. it's unbelievable :D thank you anyway

Comment: So how do we delete the photo in the folder?

Comment: It should be another controller method, with some parameters to choose the file to delete. Then the logic inside of that method with perform system.io methods to delete files on disk.